# What does the cleanup(context) method do?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I cannot understand what exactly the cleanup method in Hadoop does, and how does it function? I have the following Map-Reduce code to calculate max, min and mean of a bunch of numbers.

```
public class Statistics 
{
    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>
    {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            /* code to calculate min, max, and mean from among a bunch of numbers */
        }
        public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            Text key_min = new Text();
            key_min.set("min");
            Text value_min = new Text();
            value_min.set(String.valueOf(min));
            context.write(key_min,value_min);

            Text key_max = new Text();
            key_max.set("max");
            Text value_max = new Text();
            value_max.set(String.valueOf(max));
            context.write(key_max,value_max);

            Text key_avg = new Text();
            key_avg.set("avg");
            Text value_avg = new Text();
            value_avg.set(String.valueOf(linear_sum)+","+count);
            context.write(key_avg,value_avg);

            Text key_stddev = new Text();
            key_stddev.set("stddev");
            Text value_stddev = new Text();
            value_stddev.set(String.valueOf(linear_sum)+","+count+","+String.valueOf(quadratic_sum));
            context.write(key_stddev,value_stddev);
        }
    }
    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>
    {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            /* code to further find min, max and mean from among the outputs of different mappers */
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        /* driver program */
    }
}
```

So what exactly is the `cleanup(Context context)` method doing here? I am assuming it collects output (key, value) pairs from a bunch of mappers and passes it on to the reducer. On other sites I have read that the order things run in MapReduce is: setup -> map -> cleanup and then setup -> reduce -> cleanup. Why is this program not using a setup method?

Answer (score 1):

Such values must be calculated not in Mapper, it must be calculated **on Reduce step**.
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Reducer